# Access POST data to conditionally display form

Tags: templating, post, request, plugin-contactform

I'm working with the contact form plugin and would like to test for post data to see if the form was just submitted.

It seems this code always throws a template error.

```
Variable "test" does not exist
```

Is there a better way to do this?

```
{% set success = craft.request.getPost(test) %}
{% if success %}
    form was just submitted
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What template error does it throw?

Comment: Variable "test" does not exist—I'll add it to the question if I can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
{% set success = craft.request.getPost('test') %}
{% if success %}form was just submitted{% endif %}
```

Pass a string to `getPost()`

Comment: Looks like my issue was I didn't add quotes around the name param passed to getPost. My bad, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to test if *something* is in POST, and don't care what it is, then this should work:

```
{% set success = craft.request.getPost() | length %}

{% if success %}
    form was just submitted
{% endif %}
```